# Open UL and focus on specific LI element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi everyone and thank you in advance for trying to help.

I have a list made of several lists which looks like this:

```
<ul>
<li>
    <ul>
       <li></li>
       <li></li>
       <li></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>
    <ul>
       <li></li>
       <li></li>
       <li></li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

X Many many secondary ULs

**What i need**: I am using document.getElementById(id).scrollIntoView(true); to scroll an LI element into view. **My problem is** that this doesn't work if the UL is not expanded. Is there a way for me to find in which UL the specific ID resides in so i may expand it and focus on the LI element ?

Thank you in advance for the time dedicated trying to help noobish me

Comment: Collapsed how, LI elements aren't collapsible by default, and they generally aren't very focusable either ?

Comment: I accidently wrote collapsed instead of expanded. I need to expand the UL which is holding the required LI (with the right ID). I am focusing on elementID, which happens to be an LI. Its important that i mention that the focus works fine already if the UL is already expanded.

Comment: are you familiar with $("#id").parent() ?

Comment: So technically $(id).parent().toggle() should do it ? i'll try :)